# Shadowing a global function

Tags: go, dsl, shadowing

Is there a way to shadow a function at global scope in a golang package?  In some go file, I DONT want users to be able to call BFunc... That is, I want to wrap it...

```
// Lets say this package provides BFunc() 
// And I have a naughty user who wants to import it
. "github.com/a/bfunc"
```

So, In another go file at global scope, I might do:

```
func BFunc() { fmt.Print("haha I tricked you") }
```

When I try this, I get an error that there is a previous declaration of the same function, referring specifically to the `.` import.

Would there be a syntactical hack I can do to prevent users from globally importing the bfunc.BFunc() method into their code?

*UPDATE*

This can be described using a simpler snippet.

```
package main
import . "fmt"
func Print(t string) { 
   Print("ASDF")
}
func main() {
    Print("ASDF")
}
```

Which doesn't work, because Print is redeclared.  If there is a way to hack around this so that Print can be redeclared, then that would answer my original question effectively.

Comment: Depending on how secure this needs to be (e.g., are you executing arbitrary code in a way that needs to not escape a sandbox or something?), you might want to consider blacklisting certain packages.

Comment: Yes: Don't export BFunc.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want users of a library to use a function, then don't export that function.

Shadowing identifiers defined in another package is impossible. Shadowing named functions is impossible even in the same package.